# PDFBox doesn't recognize paragraph start when overriding processTextPosition()

Tags: java, parsing, pdfbox, paragraph

I'm using PDFBox to read a PDF file. I need the paragraphs in my text to be separated. At first, I used this code:

```
public class stripperCustom extends PDFTextStripper {

    private boolean newParagraph;

    public void parse () throws IOException {

        StringWriter outputStream = new StringWriter();
        this.writeText(this.document, outputStream);

        return elements;

    }

    @Override
    protected void writeParagraphStart () { this.newParagraph = true; }

    @Override
    protected void writeString (String string, List<TextPosition> textPositions) {

        for (Textposition tp : textPositions) {

            if (this.newParagraph) {

                ...

            }

            this.newParagraph = false;

        }

    }

}
```

This code worked perfectly, but then I realized I also needed to recognize color. After searching for a while, I realized my only option to get text color in PDFBox would be to do this instead of overriding writeText:

```
@Override
protected void processTextPosition (TextPosition textPosition) {

    super.processTextPosition(textPosition);

    PDGraphicsState graphicsState = getGraphicsState();
    System.out.println(graphicsState.getNonStrokingColor().toRGB());

}
```

This code works fine, but when, in addition, I try to get the individual paragraphs, like this

```
@Override
protected void processTextPosition (TextPosition textPosition) {

    super.processTextPosition(textPosition);

    PDGraphicsState graphicsState = getGraphicsState();
    System.out.println(graphicsState.getNonStrokingColor().toRGB());

    if (this.newParagraph) {

        ...

    }

    this.newParagraph = false;

}
```

I only get SOME paragraphs, like 10% of the original ones. I don't know why this happens, I've been looking at the parent classes and tried to override some other methods but most of them are private.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please share an example PDF for which that happens. First off, though, the problem code override you show essentially only adds a `System.out` output, and this should only have an influence on text extraction if a `NullPointerException` occurs - after all you don't check whether the `NonStrokingColor` is `null` or not, you blindly call `toRGB`. If that is not the cause of your problem, there most likely is yet another override you don't mention.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have fixed the problem already, will post the solution as soon as I have time